# how to find related questions on this website

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked some question and among many replies i saw this message:

'Please do search the site before asking, too. This question has been asked a dozen of times already'. And

'This type of question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question'.

Although i appreciated this comment, how do i search this site for my specific sentence grammar problems etc. Not everything can be found from the search tab above. Kindly do tell me how to find related answers??

Comment: Hello 73373. When you've tried your best for say 5 minutes, post your question (if it's otherwise appropriate here) anyway. Older users are bound to remember similar questions better than you can. Don't worry if it's closed for being a repeat; it will happen. Personally, I don't see how you _could_ have discovered the original in one of your posts. I managed with a search for "Using past tense when still true fact".

Comment: What Edwin said: asking a duplicate question is not actually a bad thing, as long as you did a good-faith search. When it's marked as a duplicate, your slightly-differently-worded question will become a convenient signpost to the answer, so perhaps the *next* person who has the same question will actually be able to find the answer via the site search function.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that by clicking Ask Question and typing my question in the subject, then I get a far better list than I get by using the search in the upper right.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the site's own search box, top right; it's a waste of time. I don't have much luck finding things that I *know* are there (I wrote them) that way. Instead, use a generic search engine, like Google, and enter

```
site:english.stackexchange.com my search term
```

Try it.

Comment: No, I disagree. EL&U's search box is perhaps laborious but it's worthwhile. One can search using tags, as long as it's not *grammar*, and by using the advanced search tips. It's really good for finding duplicate questions.

Comment: Except the tags don't tag anything; they overlap and contradict and leave almost everything unclear. I mostly use the search box to check my previous posts to see where I've explained something concisely so I can link it in a new answer. I rarely link any other answers here, since they're almost never put the way I would put them. But that's me, and as you point out, I don't ask many questions here.